# Constructing 95% confidence intervals for ratios where the numerator can exceed the denominator

Tags: confidence-interval

I am dealing with rate data in which the numerator (hospital visits) can exceed the denominator (population size). Obviously binomial confidence intervals don't make sense for this situation. Can anyone recommend what type of confidence intervals I can consider for this type of data?

Comment: Since follow-up time will heavily influence the probability of needing hospitalization, this is probably best cast as a recurrent event problem where time is explicitly modeled.  The results are summarized by the _mean cumulative function_  which is the mean number of times a person has been hospitalized by time $t$.  There are methods for getting confidence bands for such estimates.  You can do this with more generality using a Markov multistate transition model, handling also deaths and other events.

Comment: This is aggregate data (e.g. number of mental health visits over time period/ group of people over time period). Follow up time is not possible to include

Comment: To do a really good analysis requires using the raw data.  Can you get access to them?

Comment: Unfortunately not at this stage